# Assigning DataFrames as values to a map in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-sql

I have a list [a,b,c] (this is dynamic and list can increase or decrease)
I want to create a map as

```
a => df1
b => df2
c => df3
```

my intention is to read the list and create dataframse by reading those paths provided in the list.

```
list.map{x => dynamicalyCreatedVariable = readCSV("x")}
```

Answer (score 2):

In scala `map` function is not the same as `Map` data structure. You can create `Map` without dynamicalyCreatedVariable:

```
val paths = List("a", "b", "c")
val pathsToData: Map[String, DataFrame] = paths
  .map{ path => path -> spark.read.csv(path) }
  .toMap
```

Comment: yes, i was looking for something on these lines. thanks. but cant confirm till i get something else. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61852375/override-a-class-variable-from-parent-classes-function

Answer (score 1):

Check below code.

```
scala> val paths = Seq("a","b","c")
paths: Seq[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> val reader = spark.read.format("csv") // creating reader object
reader: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader = org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@2ce2662f

scala> paths.map(path => reader.load(path))
```