# Override a class variable from parent classes function

Tags: scala, inheritance, parent-child, extends

I have a parent and child class.

```
class a {
val name :String = "jo"
 def extract(){
  println(name)
 }
}
```

now i need to do as below.

```
class b extends a {
 override def extract(){
  override var name :String = "dave". //the problem is here and
  super.extract()
  name = "jenny" //here
  super.extract()
 }
}
```

Issues Im facing now.

1) I cannot use var if im to override the value in class a, needs to be immutable to use override.

2) needs to call the super function twice with different variable.

3) Cannot call override inside the function

Would really appreciate if anyone knew how to get around this. I cannot change anything in class a. I can work only on b and needs to call the extract function twice with different values for the variable.

Comment: You can't do `override val` inside overriding method definition. Read more about `Class scopes`. Only way to call twice `extract` is create two different objects and call `extract` on them. I suppose your main problem not in class inheritance, please provide more details about your goal here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to override super class immutable values inside method.

Instead you can change `var` in super class but don't override in child class.

Please check below code.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class a {
 var name = ""
 def extract(){
  println(name)
 }
}


class b extends a {
 override def extract(){
  name = "dave" //the problem is here and
  super.extract()
  name = "jenny" //here
  super.extract()
 }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class a
defined class b

scala> (new b).extract
dave
jenny
```

If you want to call `extract` method twice with different `name` values, Just extend parent class & override name, create child object with different name values like below.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class a {
 val name = ""
 def extract(){
  println(name)
 }
}


class b (override val name: String) extends a {
 override def extract(){
  super.extract()
 }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class a
defined class b

scala> (new b("dave")).extract
dave

scala> (new b("jenny")).extract
jenny

scala>
```

Comment: I tried the earlier answer before edit using var, but the variables where not changing before the execution of super. probably due to spark asynchronisation or something im not sure.

Comment: You have not mentioned where and how are u using these classes ..

Comment: i have a driver which calls class c which extends b

Comment: im trying to reduce the parameters. the var actually works if able to update it. the problem wasnt the spark. once the super.extract is called once the second time call also run with the frst set of variable..even though they are updated in the class b extract.

Comment: one question, why are you are calling two times super.extract method .. what is your usecase ?

Comment: to read n no of csv's. the name is actually the path and println is the read.

Comment: ok, can you add more details how are you invoking this classes ?

Comment: im just calling the extract from class c. like path = List("csv1","dfname"); df1 = extract(); path = List("csv2","dfname2"); df2 = extract();

Comment: yes thats the idea. thanks for you great help. any idea how to call the extract second time ? with the variables replaced. like new class. in class b variables are updated but inside class a they are still ones from the before call

Comment: ok, can you add some sample inputs & expected output ? I will try to build the logic .. is all csv files  schemas are same ?

Comment: it worked using var in parent and child classes. There were so many depended variables and some of them were val. thats why it was failing before. Thanks for you help. really appreciate it.